# Laser interferometry for relative movements between two mirrors

Tags: optics, laser, stability, telescopes, interferometry

I have been struggling in the past weeks to understand how should I setup a laser interferometer for my experiment. I am not a physicist, and I am quite new to optics.

I have a Cassegrain telescope with a primary mirror M1 and a secondary mirror M2 and I want to monitor the relative displacements and tilts between M1 and M2.
How can I obtain that output with the minimum number of optical components?
I am also not sure about the detector I should need.
I was thinking of a simple system that I don't know if it could actually work. I still have to purchase the components, but the budget should be around 2K.

First of all, I thought that cornercube retroreflector on both M1 and M2 would be necessary. With flat mirrors the beam would not be reflected if there is some tilt, right?
The laserbeam passes through a beamsplitter: one half goes to a right angle prism and then toward the retroreflector on M1 (can it count as the reference beam?). The other half goes to the retroreflector on M2. The beams from M1 and M2 are then recombined in the beamsplitter and the interference beam goes to the detector (PSD, quadrant photodiode?)
Would a system like this be able to give me as output the relative displacement (like a classic Michelson interferometer) and maybe the tilts (looking at the current in the quadrant photodiode perhaps)?

[image]

In the picture:
LS = laser source,
BS = beamsplitter,
P = prism,
R1-2 = retroreflectors,
QPD = quadrant photodiode.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here's the version with paths of same length
[image]

Comment: A laser interferometer is best for measuring relative displacements less than or equal to the wavelength (~1 um). Larger than that, and you need to count fringes, and you wouldn’t necessarily know which direction the mirrors are moving. What is the length scale of the mirror displacements you’re concerned about? Also, measuring displacement and interference simultaneously with the same beams is probably not recommended (analysis would be complicated; usually for interference measurements, the assumption is that the beams remain aligned).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to measure tilt and separation changes using interferometry.  As @Gilbert pointed out, for large displacements you need a way to keep track of the direction in which fringes are moving.  Actually, that's not too difficult if a video record is kept of the fringes.  An automated way to do it is to make a subsystem that locates the peak of a fringe and "dithers" the system to determine whether a sensor is on the left or right side of the peak via the relative phase of the "dithering" motion and the signal change at the sensor.  IMHO, retroreflectors should not be necessary, and might confuse the results because they don't really exactly produce a time-reversed wavefront.  It's probably best to simply set up the telescope with a laser to produce fringes that cover the field of view, get the telescope aligned the way you like it, and then monitor the fringes.  Interpreting the fringe motion in terms of change of separation, tilt angle and direction will require some assumptions and a lot of math. If you include a sketch of the setup you're contemplating, I or someone else here will gladly comment on the setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
For the retroreflectors, I thought of using them just because the reflected beams perhaps might not interfere in the beamsplitter if I use flat mirrors. Does it make sense?
Regarding the tilts, maybe it could be easier to use flat mirrors in this case, and monitor how the reflected laser beam moves on a quadrant photodiode to obtain information on its X and Y coordinates. 

Moreover, do I need a HeNe laser or a compact laser module would it be fine? Perhaps the diameter of the beam is too wide to accurately monitor its displacement on the sensors?

Comment: Flat mirrors will not prevent interference; they just need to be carefully aligned. Practically any red or green laser pointer should have plenty of coherence length for your experiment, as long as the path lengths are essentially the same.  If your quadrant detector indicates the differences between the amounts of light received by each quadrant, the beam size should not matter much.

Comment: The thing is that the surfaces themselfes where I intend to mount the flat mirrors/retroreflectors should slightly tilt during the test. In this condition, am I right to think that the reflected beam does not go back on the same direction of the incoming beam?
Do you think that a photodiode would be enough to measure the interference beam?

Comment: Presumably your tilt will be very small.  As long as the beam is coherent and is spread wide enough that the two beams overlap, the beams will interfere.  The more tilt there is, the closer together the fringes will be.  If you want to count fringes as they drift past, it's best to make sure the detector is smaller than the fringe spacing.

Comment: I'd suggest that you go ahead and set up the interferometer using a red laser pointer and flat mirrors.  Get it adjusted until you can see fringes, then adjust more until the fringes are large.  Play with placement of your photodiode and watch what happens when the fringes drift across it. You will need to spread the beam, e.g., using a microscope objective and pinhole filter, and then collimate it with a decent lens.  There will be a lot of "noise": irrelevant fringes due to dirt on the lens.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I still have some doubts though. Does it make sense to use the reflected beam from M1 as my reference beam, instead of using a fixed mirror as in the typical Michelson setup?

Comment: I still don't know exactly the configuration you have in mind; a drawing would be a big help.  In general, though, there is not an important distinction between object beam and refrrence beam, other than that the reference is usually made simple (e.g., collimated) to make interpretation of the fringe pattern simpler.

Comment: I edited the question with a picture. I have been reading today about DWS (Differential Wavefront Sensing) that employs quadrant photodiode to perform 3 Degrees of Freedom interferometric measures, using flat mirrors. Maybe that could be a good way to proceed?

Comment: OK, that helps.  I would add two mirrors in the black path to equalize the two path lengths.  This, with the addition of a lens in the combined path below the BS, should give you fringes.  With a single detector and retroreflectors (or mirrors) where you've shown, you will not be able to distinguish relative spacing and relative tilt of the two scope mirrors.  Changing relative tilt will have one principal effect: it will change the fringe spacing and orientation. Changing spacing will cause fringe position to change.  If the beams aren't well collimated, fringes curve, which confuses things.

Comment: Thank you! 
I found this paper very interesting for my setup: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6501/ab7f79/meta
"The spacing between the maxima and minima and orientation of the spatial interference pattern is correlated with the yaw [...] and pitch tilting". They use a CMOS camera as detector. 
In other papers, with a heterodyne interferometer a DWS system is used, with a quadrant photodiode with a size similar to the laser beam. Then, they compute the phase in each quadrant using Phase Locked Loops. 
With black path you mean between the laser and the beamsplitter?

Comment: By black path I meant the path between BS, P, and R2.  Yes, a phase locked loop is what you would have if you use the result of dithering to *correct* the mirror spacing/tilt.

Comment: I would like to ask you something about heterodyne systems. I have been reading here (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0957-0233/25/7/075205/meta) about a acousto-optic modulation of a laser beam to create two signals with different frequency: one is used as a reference, the other as measurement beam. Would it be the same using two different laser sources, let's say 530nm and 630nm?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be the same.  With the acousto-optic modulation method the two signals have a known phase difference due to the modulation.  With two different lasers, there is not a known phase difference: the two laser frequencies/phases will drift independently.  Also, the frequency differences will be much smaller- and controllable- with the modulation method.  If you are interested in digging deeper into heterodyne interferometry, it might be a good idea to post a new question.

Comment: Maybe better stick to that configuration adding two mirrors (or prisms?) in the path BS-P-R2 as you suggested. Maybe a beamsplitter plate (and another detector) on that path could be useful to monitor at least how the beam directed to R2 behaves with respect to the reference beam?

Comment: Just edited my question with the setup with equal length paths.

Comment: OK, last suggestions:  add a microscope objective to spread the beams, and replace the quadrant detector with a video camera.  There should be plenty of light for this.  Adjust P1 and BS until you get a good set of fringes.  You should be able to analyze any changes in the fringe pattern to determine changes in mirror spacing and tilt.  Note: all the optical components need to be firmly mounted to a base.  Might be best to test the setup's stability with the retroreflectors mounted to the same base, then to the telescope after you're sure of stability.

Comment: Looking at Thorlabs components, the microscope objective might be a bit out of my budget: it would basically collimate and magnify the beams to infinity, or something else as well? Would it be any cheap alternative? For the camera yes, I was thinking of this CMOS camera (https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=13677&pn=CS165MU#13684), it should be enough.
Some other doubts: do you think it is feasible to build a custom optical breadboard out of an Aluminium/Steel slab, or should I on the market?

Comment: An aluminum or steel slab should work fine.  It's a good idea to make all component mounts from the same material, to minimize problems when temperature changes.  Any short focal length lens will spread the beam; you might just need to give the beam more distance to spread.

Comment: For the mounting I think I would go with Thorlabs bases, posts, frames etc. The optical breadboard looks really easy to build in a workshop! May I ask you why the beams should spread? Do you mean just in way to obtain a bigger interference pattern on the camera sensor, then using a Plano-Concave lens between BS and the sensor perhaps?

Comment: The larger the interference pattern on your camera sensor, the more pixels per fringe -> more precision & accuracy in your measurements.  Any lens that spreads the beam enough will serve the purpose, though an anti-reflection coated lens would be best.

Answer (score 0):

So, this should be the setup of the experiment with the configuration we discussed about (the lens between BS and the sensor is missing): [image]

Do you think it could work?

Does it make sense to put sensors also before?
Both mirrors (reference on M1 and moving on M2) are actually moving, thus perhaps also the interference between the original laser beam and the splitted beams might be helpful and meaningful?

This should be an absolute measure, while the previous one is relative between M1 and M2.
I hope I have been clear enough.